# Conditional Statement with Data from Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, conditional-statements

I set up a `cloud-firestore` from firebase. Here I want to save if some Shop is a favorite from the user. Therefore I assigned each Shop a document favorite with the field-

> "color:" "grey" or "color:" "red".

To change the value in `firestore` I access it with this if-statement:

```
if (Firestore.instance.collection("favorites")
    .document(user1')
    .collection('shops')
    .document("$index").toString() == "grey") {...}
```

This has no effect. The program immediately jumps to the else statement.
In `Firestore` the `document 0` looks like this :

> color: "grey".

In this case 0 stands for the first shop. I applied the number 0 to it, so that I can access the shops via index.

I think it has to be something wrong with my if statement, the else function which changes the value in `firestore`, looks exactly the same, except the `toString() == 'grey'`.

```
else {Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
     await transaction.set(Firestore.instance.collection("favorites")
         .document('dd')
         .collection('shops')
         .document("$index"), {'color': 'grey',});
         });
 }
```

I do have the same problem with the conditional statement, with which I choose the color with the values in the field. With this I want to access firestore and look which value is applied to each shop:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('favorites')
    .document('dd')
    .collection("shops")
    .document("1").toString() == "grey" ? Colors.grey : Colors.red ,
```

The same problem here, it immediately jumps to the color red and every shop is marked as favorite.

Answer (score 2):

Queries to the Firestore database are asynchronous. So you if you do something like

```
Firestore.instance.collection('favorites')
.document('user1')
.collection('shops')
.document("$index").toString() == "grey"
```

it will always be false.

You have to do as explained in the [doc](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore), to wait that the promise returned by the `get()` method resolves:

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection("favorites")
    .document('user1')
    .collection('shops')
    .document("$index")
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
       // use ds as a snapshot
        const docData = ds.data;
        const color = docData["color"];

        //Do whatever you want with color value

    });
```

For more details, see https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html